# Can't get results from boolean to appear correctly

Tags: java, methods, boolean

My program asks the user for a number and then decides if the number is between the range of two randomly generated numbers or outside of it. Everything works fine, except the program keeps giving the result that the guessed number is outside the range, even when it is inside the range. Not sure how to get the answer to show correctly. Boolean result = true is there since a "Cannot find symbol" error appears if it is not.

Code:

```
public static int getValidGuess(Scanner get)
    {
       int num;

        System.out.print("Guess a number: --> ");
        num = get.nextInt();

        return num;
    } // getValidGuess end

    public static boolean displayGuessResults(int start, int end, int num)
    {
         int n1, n2;
         boolean result = true;

         Random gen = new Random();

        n1 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;
        n2 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;



        if(n1 < n2)
        {
            start = n1;
            end = n2;
        } // if end
        else
        {
            start = n2;
            end = n1;
        } //else end

        if(num > start && num < end){
             result = true;
            System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start +
                    " and " + end);
            System.out.println("Good Guess!");
        } //if end
        if(num < start || num > end){
            result = false;
            System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start +
                    " and " + end);
            System.out.println("Outside range.");
         } //if end



        return result;


    } // displayGuessResults end

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start code here
       int start = 0, end = 0, num = 0, input;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       String doAgain = "Yes";


        while (doAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
            // call method
            input = getValidGuess(scan); 
            displayGuessResults(start, end, num);
            System.out.print("\nEnter YES to repeat --> ");
            doAgain = scan.next();
        } //end while loop

    } //main end
```

Comment: It seems you don't handle the case when num==start or num == end; then you quietly return `true`

Answer (score 0):

Your `displayGuessResult` should be improved:

```
public static boolean displayGuessResults(int num) {
    boolean result = true;

    Random gen = new Random();

    int n1 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;
    int n2 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;
    int start = Math.min(n1, n2);
    int end   = Math.max(n1, n2);

    System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start + " and " + end);
    if(num >= start && num <= end){
        result = true;
        System.out.println("Good Guess!");
    } else {
        result = false;
        System.out.println("Outside range.");
    }
    return result;
} // displayGuessResults end
```

and you have to call it using `input` read from the Scanner:

```
    input = getValidGuess(scan); 
    displayGuessResults(input);
```